# Why do we need MSIL in .net Framework

Tags: c#, cil

I wanna know when we compile .net source code it gets first converted to MSIL and then into binary executable code. I know MSIL is machine and language independent code.

But why it is converted to MSIL first before gets executed by CPU. What is the need of MSIL actually we have in .net framework ?

Comment: Wow. This topic has been done to death over the years. Could you seriously not find any articles/blogs related to this through Google?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of the top of my head:

- It saves a lot of time, as MSIL is already optimized, let´s call it
  precompiled
- MSIL is language independent, it doesn´t matter anymore
  if the code was written in C#, VB or F# or ..., meaning the "excecuting runtime" doesn´t need the correct compiler for every possible language
- MSIL is platform independent
- Google it

Comment: also: sanity/validation by the loader. It is very hard to check CPU codes, but IL retains the intent

Comment: @jobo google reached me here, now what..??